# My javascript is not working on html

Tags: javascript, html

Below is a simple registration form.  nothing happens when i click on sign up. why is this happening. can anyone please help. i am not able to understand why its not happening ,everything seems correct to me.

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    *{
     margin:0px;
     padding:0px;
     }
    body{
     font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
     }
    #container{
     width:550px;
     background-color:rgba(250,250,252,.9);
     margin:auto;
     margin-top:10px;
     margin-bottom:10px;
     box-shadow:0 0 3px #999;
     }
    #container_body{
     padding:20px;
     }
    .form_title{
     font-size:35px;
     color:#141823;
     text-align:center;
     padding:10px;
     font-weight:normal;
     }
    .head_para{
     font-size:19px;
     color:#99a2a7;
     text-align:center;
     font-weight:normal;
     }
    #form_name{
     padding:25px 0 0 15px;
     }
    .firstnameorlastname{
      margin-right:20px;
     }
    .input_name{
     width:207px;
     padding:5px;
     font-size:18px;
     }
    #email_form{
     clear:both;
     padding:15px 0 10px 0px;
     }
    .input_email{
     width:434px;
     padding:5px;
     font-size:18px;
     }
    #Re_email_form{
     padding:10px 0 10px 0px;
     }
    .input_Re_email{
     width:434px;
     padding:5px;
     font-size:18px;
     }
    #password_form{
     padding:10px 0 10px 0px;
     }
    .input_password{
     width:434px;
     padding:5px;
     font-size:18px;
     }
    .birthday_title{
     font-size:16px;
     color:#8b919d;
     font-weight:normal;
     padding:0 0 10px 0;
     }
    select{
     padding:5px;
     }
    #birthday{
     font-size:12px;
     color:#8b919d;
     padding-top:10px;
     }
    #radio_button{
     padding:10px 0 0 0;
     }
    #sign_user{
     font-size:14px;
     color:#FFF;
     text-align:center;
     background-color:#3B5998;
     padding:10px;
     margin-top:10px;
     cursor: pointer;
     }
    #errorBox{
     color:#F00;
     }
    </style>
    <script>
    function Submit(){
     var emailRegex = /^[A-Za-z0-9._]*\@[A-Za-z]*\.[A-Za-z]{2,5}$/;
     var fname = document.form.Name.value,
      lname = document.form.LastName.value,
      femail = document.form.Email.value,
      freemail = document.form.enterEmail.value,
      fpassword = document.form.Password.value,
      fmonth = document.form.birthday_month.value,
      fday = document.form.birthday_day.value,
      fyear = document.form.birthday_year.value;

     if( fname == "" )
       {
         document.form.Name.focus() ;
      document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "enter the first name";
         return false;
       }
     if( lname == "" )
       {
         document.form.LastName.focus() ;
       document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "enter the last name";
         return false;
       }

       if (femail == "" )
     {
      document.form.Email.focus();
      document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "enter the email";
      return false;
      }else if(!emailRegex.test(femail)){
      document.form.Email.focus();
      document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "enter the valid email";
      return false;
      }

       if (freemail == "" )
     {
      document.form.enterEmail.focus();
      document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "Re-enter the email";
      return false;
      }else if(!emailRegex.test(freemail)){
      document.form.enterEmail.focus();
      document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "Re-enter the valid email";
      return false;
      }

      if(freemail !=  femail){
       document.form.enterEmail.focus();
       document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "emails are not matching, re-enter again";
       return false;
       }


     if(fpassword == "")
      {
       document.form.Password.focus();
       document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "enter the password";
       return false;
      }

       if (fmonth == "") {
            document.form.birthday_month.focus();
      document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "select the birthday month";
            return false;
         }
      if (fday == "") {
            document.form.birthday_day.focus();
      document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "select the birthday day";
            return false;
         }
      if (fyear == "") {
            document.form.birthday_year.focus();
      document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "select the birthday year";
            return false;
         }
      if(document.form.radiobutton[0].checked == false && document.form.radiobutton[1].checked == false){
        document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "select your gender";
        return false;
       }
      if(fname != '' && lname != '' && femail != '' && freemail != '' && fpassword != '' && fmonth != '' && fday != '' && fyear != ''){
       document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "form submitted successfully";
       }
        </script> 
    </head>
    <<body>
    <div id="emptyDiv">


    </div>
    <div id="description"></div>
    <!--container start-->
    <div id="container">
      <div id="container_body">
        <div>
          <h2 class="form_title">User Registration Form Demo</h2>
          <p class="head_para">Form Validated Using Javascript</p>
        </div>
        <!--Form  start-->
        <div id="form_name">
          <div class="firstnameorlastname">
           <form name="form" >
           <div id="errorBox"></div>
            <input type="text" name="Name" value="" placeholder="First Name"  class="input_name" >
            <input type="text" name="LastName" value="" placeholder="Last Name" class="input_name" >

          </div>
          <div id="email_form">
            <input type="text" name="Email" value=""  placeholder="Your Email" class="input_email">
          </div>
          <div id="Re_email_form">
            <input type="text" name="enterEmail" value=""  placeholder="Re-enter Email" class="input_Re_email">
          </div>
          <div id="password_form">
            <input type="password" name="Password" value=""  placeholder="New Password" class="input_password">
          </div>
          <!--birthday details start-->
          <div>
            <h3 class="birthday_title">Birthday</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <select name="birthday_month" >
              <option value="" selected >Month</option>
              <option value="1">Jan</option>
              <option value="2">Feb</option>
              <option value="3">Mar</option>
              <option value="4">Apr</option>
              <option value="5">May</option>
              <option value="6">Jun</option>
              <option value="7">Jul</option>
              <option value="8">Aug</option>
              <option value="9">Sep</option>
              <option value="10">Oct</option>
              <option value="11">Nov</option>
              <option value="12">Dec</option>
            </select>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;
            <select name="birthday_day" >
              <option value="" selected>Day</option>
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
              <option value="3">3</option>
              <option value="4">4</option>
              <option value="5">5</option>
              <option value="6">6</option>
              <option value="7">7</option>
              <option value="8">8</option>
              <option value="9">9</option>
              <option value="10">10</option>
              <option value="11">11</option>
              <option value="12">12</option>
              <option value="13">13</option>
              <option value="14">14</option>
              <option value="15">15</option>
              <option value="16">16</option>
              <option value="17">17</option>
              <option value="18">18</option>
              <option value="19">19</option>
              <option value="20">20</option>
              <option value="21">21</option>
              <option value="22">22</option>
              <option value="23">23</option>
              <option value="24">24</option>
              <option value="25">25</option>
              <option value="26">26</option>
              <option value="27">27</option>
              <option value="28">28</option>
              <option value="29">29</option>
              <option value="30">30</option>
              <option value="31">31</option>
            </select>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;
            <select name="birthday_year">
              <option value="" selected>Year</option>
              <option value="2013">2013</option>
              <option value="2012">2012</option>
              <option value="2011">2011</option>
              <option value="2010">2010</option>
              <option value="2009">2009</option>
              <option value="2008">2008</option>
              <option value="2007">2007</option>
              <option value="2006">2006</option>
              <option value="2005">2005</option>
              <option value="2004">2004</option>
              <option value="2003">2003</option>
              <option value="2002">2002</option>
              <option value="2001">2001</option>
              <option value="2000">2000</option>
              <option value="1999">1999</option>
              <option value="1998">1998</option>
              <option value="1997">1997</option>
              <option value="1996">1996</option>
              <option value="1995">1995</option>
              <option value="1994">1994</option>
              <option value="1993">1993</option>
              <option value="1992">1992</option>
              <option value="1991">1991</option>
              <option value="1990">1990</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <!--birthday details ends-->
          <div id="radio_button">
            <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="Female">
            <label >Female</label>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="Male">
            <label >Male</label>
          </div>
           <div>
            <Button id="sign_user" onClick=" return Submit();">Sign Up
          </div>
         </form>
        </div>
        <!--form ends--> 
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--container ends-->
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: any console errors in your browser? if you can, please share a fiddle with us..

Comment: nope no console errors appearing....it just empties the field afer i click on button

Comment: Use a debugger. There's no point in us guessing - follow your code and see where it breaks.

Comment: I have update myanswer check it and let me know

Comment: please check the answer

Comment: If your purpose is solved ,Mark accept the answer.

Comment: Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting about help with debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...
You missed 1)Button close tag 2)submit functions closing bracket {

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }

        body {
            font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
        }

        #container {
            width: 550px;
            background-color: rgba(250,250,252,.9);
            margin: auto;
            margin-top: 10px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            box-shadow: 0 0 3px #999;
        }

        #container_body {
            padding: 20px;
        }

        .form_title {
            font-size: 35px;
            color: #141823;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 10px;
            font-weight: normal;
        }

        .head_para {
            font-size: 19px;
            color: #99a2a7;
            text-align: center;
            font-weight: normal;
        }

        #form_name {
            padding: 25px 0 0 15px;
        }

        .firstnameorlastname {
            margin-right: 20px;
        }

        .input_name {
            width: 207px;
            padding: 5px;
            font-size: 18px;
        }

        #email_form {
            clear: both;
            padding: 15px 0 10px 0px;
        }

        .input_email {
            width: 434px;
            padding: 5px;
            font-size: 18px;
        }

        #Re_email_form {
            padding: 10px 0 10px 0px;
        }

        .input_Re_email {
            width: 434px;
            padding: 5px;
            font-size: 18px;
        }

        #password_form {
            padding: 10px 0 10px 0px;
        }

        .input_password {
            width: 434px;
            padding: 5px;
            font-size: 18px;
        }

        .birthday_title {
            font-size: 16px;
            color: #8b919d;
            font-weight: normal;
            padding: 0 0 10px 0;
        }

        select {
            padding: 5px;
        }

        #birthday {
            font-size: 12px;
            color: #8b919d;
            padding-top: 10px;
        }

        #radio_button {
            padding: 10px 0 0 0;
        }

        #sign_user {
            font-size: 14px;
            color: #FFF;
            text-align: center;
            background-color: #3B5998;
            padding: 10px;
            margin-top: 10px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        #errorBox {
            color: #F00;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        function Submit() {

            var emailRegex = /^[A-Za-z0-9._]*\@[A-Za-z]*\.[A-Za-z]{2,5}$/;

            var fname = document.form.Name.value,
             lname = document.form.LastName.value,
             femail = document.form.Email.value,
             freemail = document.form.enterEmail.value,
             fpassword = document.form.Password.value,
             fmonth = document.form.birthday_month.value,
             fday = document.form.birthday_day.value,
             fyear = document.form.birthday_year.value;

            if (fname == "") {
                document.form.Name.focus();
                document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "enter the first name";
                return false;
            }
            if (lname == "") {
                document.form.LastName.focus();
                document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "enter the last name";
                return false;
            }

            if (femail == "") {
                document.form.Email.focus();
                document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "enter the email";
                return false;
            } else if (!emailRegex.test(femail)) {
                document.form.Email.focus();
                document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "enter the valid email";
                return false;
            }

            if (freemail == "") {
                document.form.enterEmail.focus();
                document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "Re-enter the email";
                return false;
            } else if (!emailRegex.test(freemail)) {
                document.form.enterEmail.focus();
                document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "Re-enter the valid email";
                return false;
            }

            if (freemail != femail) {
                document.form.enterEmail.focus();
                document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "emails are not matching, re-enter again";
                return false;
            }


            if (fpassword == "") {
                document.form.Password.focus();
                document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "enter the password";
                return false;
            }

            if (fmonth == "") {
                document.form.birthday_month.focus();
                document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "select the birthday month";
                return false;
            }
            if (fday == "") {
                document.form.birthday_day.focus();
                document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "select the birthday day";
                return false;
            }
            if (fyear == "") {
                document.form.birthday_year.focus();
                document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "select the birthday year";
                return false;
            }
            if (document.form.radiobutton[0].checked == false && document.form.radiobutton[1].checked == false) {
                document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "select your gender";
                return false;
            }
            if (fname != '' && lname != '' && femail != '' && freemail != '' && fpassword != '' && fmonth != '' && fday != '' && fyear != '') {
                document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "form submitted successfully";
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
    <
<body>
    <div id="emptyDiv">


    </div>
    <div id="description"></div>
    <!--container start-->
    <div id="container">
        <div id="container_body">
            <div>
                <h2 class="form_title">User Registration Form Demo</h2>
                <p class="head_para">Form Validated Using Javascript</p>
            </div>
            <!--Form  start-->
            <div id="form_name">
                <div class="firstnameorlastname">
                    <form name="form">
                        <div id="errorBox"></div>
                        <input type="text" name="Name" value="" placeholder="First Name" class="input_name">
                        <input type="text" name="LastName" value="" placeholder="Last Name" class="input_name">

                </div>
                <div id="email_form">
                    <input type="text" name="Email" value="" placeholder="Your Email" class="input_email">
                </div>
                <div id="Re_email_form">
                    <input type="text" name="enterEmail" value="" placeholder="Re-enter Email" class="input_Re_email">
                </div>
                <div id="password_form">
                    <input type="password" name="Password" value="" placeholder="New Password" class="input_password">
                </div>
                <!--birthday details start-->
                <div>
                    <h3 class="birthday_title">Birthday</h3>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <select name="birthday_month">
                        <option value="" selected>Month</option>
                        <option value="1">Jan</option>
                        <option value="2">Feb</option>
                        <option value="3">Mar</option>
                        <option value="4">Apr</option>
                        <option value="5">May</option>
                        <option value="6">Jun</option>
                        <option value="7">Jul</option>
                        <option value="8">Aug</option>
                        <option value="9">Sep</option>
                        <option value="10">Oct</option>
                        <option value="11">Nov</option>
                        <option value="12">Dec</option>
                    </select>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <select name="birthday_day">
                        <option value="" selected>Day</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="6">6</option>
                        <option value="7">7</option>
                        <option value="8">8</option>
                        <option value="9">9</option>
                        <option value="10">10</option>
                        <option value="11">11</option>
                        <option value="12">12</option>
                        <option value="13">13</option>
                        <option value="14">14</option>
                        <option value="15">15</option>
                        <option value="16">16</option>
                        <option value="17">17</option>
                        <option value="18">18</option>
                        <option value="19">19</option>
                        <option value="20">20</option>
                        <option value="21">21</option>
                        <option value="22">22</option>
                        <option value="23">23</option>
                        <option value="24">24</option>
                        <option value="25">25</option>
                        <option value="26">26</option>
                        <option value="27">27</option>
                        <option value="28">28</option>
                        <option value="29">29</option>
                        <option value="30">30</option>
                        <option value="31">31</option>
                    </select>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <select name="birthday_year">
                        <option value="" selected>Year</option>
                        <option value="2013">2013</option>
                        <option value="2012">2012</option>
                        <option value="2011">2011</option>
                        <option value="2010">2010</option>
                        <option value="2009">2009</option>
                        <option value="2008">2008</option>
                        <option value="2007">2007</option>
                        <option value="2006">2006</option>
                        <option value="2005">2005</option>
                        <option value="2004">2004</option>
                        <option value="2003">2003</option>
                        <option value="2002">2002</option>
                        <option value="2001">2001</option>
                        <option value="2000">2000</option>
                        <option value="1999">1999</option>
                        <option value="1998">1998</option>
                        <option value="1997">1997</option>
                        <option value="1996">1996</option>
                        <option value="1995">1995</option>
                        <option value="1994">1994</option>
                        <option value="1993">1993</option>
                        <option value="1992">1992</option>
                        <option value="1991">1991</option>
                        <option value="1990">1990</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <!--birthday details ends-->
                <div id="radio_button">
                    <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="Female">
                    <label>Female</label>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="Male">
                    <label>Male</label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button id="sign_user" onclick=" return Submit();">Sign Up</button>
                </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <!--form ends-->
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--container ends-->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

You didnt close "Submit" function.The "}" is missing

```
function Submit(){
     var emailRegex = /^[A-Za-z0-9._]*\@[A-Za-z]*\.[A-Za-z]{2,5}$/;
     var fname = document.form.Name.value,
      lname = document.form.LastName.value,
      femail = document.form.Email.value,
      freemail = document.form.enterEmail.value,
      fpassword = document.form.Password.value,
      fmonth = document.form.birthday_month.value,
      fday = document.form.birthday_day.value,
      fyear = document.form.birthday_year.value;

     if( fname == "" )
       {
         document.form.Name.focus() ;
      document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "enter the first name";
         return false;
       }
     if( lname == "" )
       {
         document.form.LastName.focus() ;
       document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "enter the last name";
         return false;
       }

       if (femail == "" )
     {
      document.form.Email.focus();
      document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "enter the email";
      return false;
      }else if(!emailRegex.test(femail)){
      document.form.Email.focus();
      document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "enter the valid email";
      return false;
      }

       if (freemail == "" )
     {
      document.form.enterEmail.focus();
      document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "Re-enter the email";
      return false;
      }else if(!emailRegex.test(freemail)){
      document.form.enterEmail.focus();
      document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "Re-enter the valid email";
      return false;
      }

      if(freemail !=  femail){
       document.form.enterEmail.focus();
       document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "emails are not matching, re-enter again";
       return false;
       }


     if(fpassword == "")
      {
       document.form.Password.focus();
       document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "enter the password";
       return false;
      }

       if (fmonth == "") {
            document.form.birthday_month.focus();
      document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "select the birthday month";
            return false;
         }
      if (fday == "") {
            document.form.birthday_day.focus();
      document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "select the birthday day";
            return false;
         }
      if (fyear == "") {
            document.form.birthday_year.focus();
      document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "select the birthday year";
            return false;
         }
      if(document.form.radiobutton[0].checked == false && document.form.radiobutton[1].checked == false){
        document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "select your gender";
        return false;
       }
      if(fname != '' && lname != '' && femail != '' && freemail != '' && fpassword != '' && fmonth != '' && fday != '' && fyear != ''){
       document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "form submitted successfully";
       }
       }
```

Demo:http://js.do/code/67286